# Запуск bash скрипта вместе с приложением

Tags: javascript, linux, bash

Всем привет. Подскажите, имеется ОС Linux (Debian) и приложение почты ThunderBird. К нему штатными средствами написан конфиг, который производит автонастройку почты пользователя. Все прекрасно работает, но возникла необходимость еще по мимо штатной настройки, конфиг которой лежит в папке с почтой и написан на JS'e подгружать bash скрипт при запуске приложения. Как то это возможно реализовать?

Comment: Подменить приложение скриптом, очевидно.

Answer (score 0):

`alias thunderbird=/path/to/script;/usr/bin/thunderbird` для запуска из терминала

или отредактировать схожим образом пункт Command в desktop-файле

Comment: Не совсем подходит. Люди не самые умные работают, но с большой фантазией и в итоге как нибудь запустят почту в обход этого ярлыка.

Comment: @Bek1zo если всё настолько сложно, то наверное проще написать watchdog, наблюдающий за списком процессов и запускающий скрипт при появлении в нём thunderbird.

еще можно заменить /usr/bin/thunderbird своим скриптом, который в конце себя запустит оригинальный файл (переименованный в thunderbird_orig или типа того), но это решение до первого обновления thunderbird системой